Error when running flutter application after updating xcode 16 (using image picker library)
I’m facing an issue after updating to Xcode 16 with my Flutter project, specifically related to the image_picker_ios package. When I try to build the project for an iOS simulator or real device, I receive errors saying that Flutter/Flutter.h is missing.
Environment:
•   Flutter version: 3.16
•   Dart version: 3.2.6
•   Xcode version: 16
•   image_picker version: 1.0.8
•   Target iOS deployment version: iOS 12.0
•   Device: iPhone 15 Pro simulator running iOS 17.0

Error Details:
The build fails with the following errors:
error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found (in target 'image_picker_ios' from project 'Pods')
Here are some specific lines that appear in the error log:
•   /Users/myuser/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.9+2/ios/Classes/messages.g.m:12:9: error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
•   /Users/myuser/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/image_picker_ios-0.8.9+2/ios/Classes/FLTPHPickerSaveImageToPathOperation.m:5:9: error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

(I checked them and the import is there, which is really weird is that I have another project with same library same versions and it just works.)
Steps I’ve Tried:
I’ve tried the following troubleshooting steps, but the issue persists:
1.  Updating the Podfile: I set platform :ios, '12.0' and added use_frameworks! and use_modular_headers!.
2.  Reinstalling Pods and Cleaning:
•   Ran flutter clean, rm -rf ios/Pods ios/Podfile.lock, then pod install.
•   I also tried flutter pub get and flutter run afterward.
3.  Testing on a Physical Device: Same issue occurs on both the simulator and an actual device.
4.  Dependency Reinstallation: I removed and reinstalled image_picker with image_picker_ios 0.8.9+2, which is the latest stable version.
5.  Checking Framework Search Paths in Xcode: Made sure $(inherited) and Flutter.framework paths were included in the Framework Search Paths in Xcode.

But not working, it's really frustrating. I even tried to clonning it from another version I had previously and same errors appear when running.
Has anyone encountered similar issues with Flutter/Flutter.h missing after updating to Xcode 16, especially with image_picker_ios? Are there additional steps or configurations I need to adjust to get the build to recognize the Flutter framework headers? Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated!
Interestingly, I have another Flutter project using image_picker that builds fine on Xcode 16, with the same target iOS version. I suspect the issue may be related to dependencies in my current project or something in Xcode’s handling of certain header files.

Can you provide your Podfile ?

Solution: Credit to "techworks" for this solution! his video provided clear steps that finally got my project working. You can find their video here: link yt
Leave it here, for anyone else who faces this issue.
